# Python get the name of all fields in a dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.9, python-dataclasses

I am trying to write a function to log dataclasses I would like to get the name of all fields in the dataclass and print the value to each (similar to how you might write a function to print a dictionary)

i.e.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    a: str = "a value"
    b: str = "b value"


test = Test()
def print_data_class(dataclass_instance):
   fields = # get dataclass fileds
   for field in fields:
       print(f{field}: {dataclass.field})
print_data_class(test)

-->
"a"  : "a value"
"b"  : "b value"
```

However I haven't been able to find how to get the fields of a dataclass, does anyone know how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This example shows only a name, type and value, however, `__dataclass_fields__` is a dict of [`Field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=field#dataclasses.Field) objects, each containing information such as `name`, `type`, `default value`, etc.

### Using dataclasses.fields()

Using [`dataclasses.fields()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=field#dataclasses.fields) you can access fields you defined in your dataclass.

```py
fields = dataclasses.fields(dataclass_instance)
```

### Using inspect.getmembers()

Using [`inspect.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) you can access all fields in your dataclass.

```py
members = inspect.getmembers(type(dataclass_instance))
fields = list(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == '__dataclass_fields__', members))[0][1].values())
```

### Complete code solution

```py
import dataclasses
import inspect


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    a: str = "a value"
    b: str = "b value"


def print_data_class(dataclass_instance):

    # option 1: fields
    fields = dataclasses.fields(dataclass_instance)

    # option 2: inspect
    members = inspect.getmembers(type(dataclass_instance))
    fields = list(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == '__dataclass_fields__', members))[0][1].values())

    for v in fields:
      print(f'{v.name}: ({v.type.__name__}) = {getattr(dataclass_instance, v.name)}')


print_data_class(Test())
# a: (str) = a value
# b: (str) = b value

print_data_class(Test(a="1", b="2"))
# a: (str) = 1
# b: (str) = 2
```

Comment: That unholy string of filter/lambda/indices seems unnecessary when you've already demonstrated the nice, clean method that's available. Is there any kind of advantage to it?

Comment: @CrazyChucky the only difference is that `inspect` gives you access to more information other than these fields you defined (e.g. `__annotations__`, `__dataclass_params__`, `__doc__`, etc.)

Comment: You don't need to pass a `dataclass_instance` to `fields()`, the class itself works, too.

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == '__dataclass_fields__', inspect.getmembers(type(dataclass_instance))))[0][1]` is an overly complicated way of writing `type(dataclass_instance).__dataclass_fields__`.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can use `__annotations__`, well, because data fields are *always* annotated. This is the essense of dataclasses usage.

It works with classes

```py
    fields = list(Test.__annotations__)
```

and with instances

```py
    fields = list(test.__annotations__)
```

There should be noted that it doesn't work with dataclass subclasses. Obviously. However, simplicity gives you fields names directly, without extra code for extraction from Field objects.

Comment: Good answer if you want to get the fields from the class definition instead of the instance

Answer (score 3):

use the `__dict__` property

```py
def print_data_class(dataclass_instance):
   fields = [(attribute, value) for attribute, value in dataclass_instance.__dict__.items()]
   for field in fields:
       print("{}: {}".format(*field))
```

Comment: I think you may have meant ```dataclass_instance.__dict__.items()``` and ```print("f{field[0]}: {field[1]}"``` but other than that works great thanks

Comment: I had assumed that as dataclasses aren't normal classes that wouldn't work

Comment: Note that this will also get other attributes set at runtime, not just fields defined in the dataclass.